# How to break matrix?

Tags: matrices

I want to write 10 x 10 matrix in A5 paper, but not enough space. So I want to break matrix into two part.

First part contains first column until fifth column, and second part contains sixth column until tenth column.

This is my code

```
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    -1.25612&4.57139&1.18800&4.75634&11.3930\\
    25.3546&-23.9185&-9.25578&-23.5826&-67.0936\\
    2.62290&-2.92613&2.88630&-2.21070&-7.27543\\
    -10.8734&11.6225&3.87934&13.1553&29.5466\\
    -17.7935&18.9282&6.67018&17.2205&50.4455\\
    1.69807&-1.77634&-0.784606&-1.62226&-4.65618\\
    2.28798&-2.41496&-0.895028&-2.00945&-6.46447\\
    4.84056&-5.05856&-2.17046&-4.53312&-12.3609\\
    13.3794&-14.3065&-4.53767&-11.9704&-35.3721\\
    -1.75425&1.83716&0.890361&1.65914&4.16173
    \end{bmatrix}\\
    \begin{bmatrix}
    7.62531&9.29222&8.93318&4.90767&11.4612\\
    -51.2563&-56.3985&-46.4690&-25.0533&-62.6778\\
    -4.89938&-6.99693&-4.81757&-2.51625&-5.84317\\
    22.3327&25.8681&20.8973&11.1549&28.0619\\
    36.6216&39.8738&33.6386&18.2052&45.5202\\
    0.0240615&-4.11393&-3.63169&-1.85983&-4.85244\\
    -4.73874&-2.65149&-4.53585&-2.55040&-6.00507\\
    -9.81447&-9.80620&-5.48529&-4.55776&-11.8261\\
    -26.0706&-31.2828&-24.5042&-9.49538&-32.9412\\
    2.04859&4.16513&2.76542&1.25894&6.29555
    \end{bmatrix}
    $$
```

But the code above cannot break into two part, and the bracket appear 2 times.

How to break matrix?

Comment: Welcome on [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/), you can check this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277001/split-a-multiline-bmatrix)

Comment: Is there a reason that motivates the specific use of a `bmatrix` environment ?

Comment: I want to create matrix with box bracket, so I use bmatrix.

Comment: What is the purpose of this document ? I am asking this besause I personally do not really like matrices cut over two pages.

Comment: You need to defeat Agent Smith. `:)` *(oh my, terrible joke about breaking the Matrix...)* Anyway, welcome to TeX.sx! `:)`

Comment: Off-topic, but please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Comment: @BambOo for my final project. My final project use A5 paper so if I write 10 x 10 matrix, the space is not enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `multline`, along with `siunitx` features for pretty printing the data.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
\left[
    \begin{tabular}{ @{} *{5}{S[table-format=-2.5,group-digits=false,round-mode=places,round-precision=5]} @{} }
    -1.25612&4.57139&1.18800&4.75634&11.3930\\
    25.3546&-23.9185&-9.25578&-23.5826&-67.0936\\
    2.62290&-2.92613&2.88630&-2.21070&-7.27543\\
    -10.8734&11.6225&3.87934&13.1553&29.5466\\
    -17.7935&18.9282&6.67018&17.2205&50.4455\\
    1.69807&-1.77634&-0.784606&-1.62226&-4.65618\\
    2.28798&-2.41496&-0.895028&-2.00945&-6.46447\\
    4.84056&-5.05856&-2.17046&-4.53312&-12.3609\\
    13.3794&-14.3065&-4.53767&-11.9704&-35.3721\\
    -1.75425&1.83716&0.890361&1.65914&4.16173
    \end{tabular}
\right.
\\
\left.
    \begin{tabular}{ @{} *{5}{S[table-format=-2.5,group-digits=false,round-mode=places,round-precision=5]} @{} }
    7.62531&9.29222&8.93318&4.90767&11.4612\\
    -51.2563&-56.3985&-46.4690&-25.0533&-62.6778\\
    -4.89938&-6.99693&-4.81757&-2.51625&-5.84317\\
    22.3327&25.8681&20.8973&11.1549&28.0619\\
    36.6216&39.8738&33.6386&18.2052&45.5202\\
    0.0240615&-4.11393&-3.63169&-1.85983&-4.85244\\
    -4.73874&-2.65149&-4.53585&-2.55040&-6.00507\\
    -9.81447&-9.80620&-5.48529&-4.55776&-11.8261\\
    -26.0706&-31.2828&-24.5042&-9.49538&-32.9412\\
    2.04859&4.16513&2.76542&1.25894&6.29555
    \end{tabular}
\right]
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

[image]